# How do I do an advanced search that lists all the employees within organizations that are in a "group"

Tags: advanced-search

I want to export a list of all the employees ("employee of") our member organizations that are part of a group.
I'm using the advanced search option, but can't figure it out.

Under relationships, I've checked "employee of" and then in the target group, selected the group. But it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SE!  That should work. When you say 'it doesn't work' - do you mean there are no results, or there are some but not what you expect or ...?

Comment: Just to be clear that I have parsed you question correctly. I'm assuming that you mean its the organisations (not the employees) who are in the group you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

Set up a search in Advanced Search as though you were looking for the organizations.  Then, at the top, for *Display Results As*, select **Related Contacts** and **Employee of**.  Unless it's Employer of?  One of those should work :)
[image]

Comment: I don't think that quite answers the question. I think the problem is that the "Target Contact(s) in Group" field in the relationships part of the search doesn't work. I get no reponses when I create a group of all organisations with "London" in the name, but I do get the right results when I search for partial name of "London" in the "Target Contact" field above